# How to throw error for missing environment variable at build time in node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, environment-variables

I'm using `.env` file to store variables, and this is used by my typescript node project. I can check for missing env vars at the runtime and throw an error if it's not present.

```
export const SOME_KEY = process.env.SOME_KEY || ""
if (!SOME_KEY) {
  throw new Error("SOME_KEY is missing from .env file")
}
```

However, is there a way I could check all necessary env vars at build time instead? Probably some separate node script that gets executed at the build command? Note that my project is built on Typescript, so I guess it kind of makes it a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a step before the `build` that just loops over an array of needed `env` vars and just bails if something is off.

You probably have a build script, something like this in your `package.json`

```
{
 "scripts": {
   "build": "...your build command here"
 }
}
```

You can add a `prebuild` script that just checks for this.

```
{
 "scripts": {
  "prebuild": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev check_env_vars.ts"
 } 
}
```

Note, that I'm using [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) to execute TS. This should be installed as a dev deps and not a build dev.

You could also just run this before your build command, something like this:

```
{
 "scripts": {
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev check_env_vars.ts && ... old build command"
 }
}
```

If you `throw` from `check_env_vars.ts` the build command will stop, so that's a benefit.